# Separate CSV import fields in a query

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I would to load a csv into MySQL and manage the single field. the original code uploaded the content with automatic `VALUES('','$linemysql');`. How can I separate the fields? I would a query like:

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `database`.`table` (`field1`,field2`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5`) VALUES(`csvfield1`,csvfield2`, `csvfield3`, `csvfield4`, `csvfield5`);";
```

This because I can manage which row will be included

```
$lines = 0;
$queries = "";
$linearray = array();

$allLines = split($lineseparator,$csvcontent);
array_shift($allLines); // removes the 1st element

foreach($allLines as $line) {

$lines++;

$line = trim($line," \t");

$line = str_replace("\r","",$line);

/************************************
This line escapes the special character. remove it if entries are already escaped in the csv file
************************************/
$line = str_replace("'","\'",$line);
/*************************************/

$linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$line);

$linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);

if($addauto)

/* Change This query VALUES('','$linemysql'); */

    $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `database`.`table` (`field1`,field2`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5`) VALUES('','$linemysql');";
            
else
    $query = "insert into $databasetable values('$linemysql');";

$queries .= $query . "\n";
```

Comment: Use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's built in CSV functionality including [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). From the docs:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your query like this

```
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `database`.`table` (`field1`,field2`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5`) VALUES("'.$linemysql[0].'","'.$linemysql[1].'","'.$linemysql[2].'","'.$linemysql[3].'","'.$linemysql[4].'");";
```

Thanks

Comment: I think is correct but report this error : 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING